# When is Fisher Information the reciprocal of the variance?

Tags: probability, mathematical-statistics, inference, fisher-information

I notice that for many common distributions (e.g., Bernoulli, Exponential), the Fisher Information is the same as the reciprocal of the population variance.

When is this true? Is there a theorem that states than if conditions X, Y, and Z are true, then we have that
$$
I(\theta ;X) = \frac{1}{\text{Var}(X)}
$$

Comment: I'm not seeing how Slutsky's theorem applies here...?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In both those cases (Bernoulli and exponential) the MLE estimator is the identity function.  This gives a clue as to how to proceed.  Here is a theorem giving sufficient conditions for this result.

> **Theorem:** Consider a family of distributions $\{ F_\theta | \theta \in \Theta \}$.  If the estimator $\hat{\theta}(x) = x$ (i.e., the identity estimator) is efficient, then we have:
>
> $$\mathcal{I}(\theta) = \frac{1}{\mathbb{V}(X)}.$$
>
> **Proof:** The variance of the identity estimator is $\mathbb{V}(\hat{\theta}) = \mathbb{V}(X)$.  If the estimator is efficient then (by definition) it achieves the [Cramér–Rao bound](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cram%C3%A9r%E2%80%93Rao_bound), so we then have:
>
> $$\mathbb{V}(\hat{\theta}) = \frac{1}{\mathcal{I}(\theta)}.$$
>
> Putting these two results together gives the required result.  $\blacksquare$